# Google Disk как сервер хранения изображений для своего приложения

Tags: android, google-drive

Меня интересует следующий вопрос: можно ли воспользоваться сервисом Google Disk для размещения изображений для своего приложения? Картинок будет немало, порядка нескольких десятков тысяч, размером 10-30 кБ каждая. Предполагаемая модель использования:

1. Грузим картинки в GD, даем к ним открытый доступ и получаем прямые ссылки на них;
2. В своем приложении, а именно в БД вбиваем эти ссылки, для последующей их передачи, например в Picasso для загрузки и кеширования. Выводиться картинки будут в RecyclerView.

Какие-либо манипуляции с картинками не предполагаются ибо они играют роль логотипов. Все что требуется - только хранение, чтобы эти файлы не держать в самом приложении.

Данный подход работает для меня, но что будет, если приложение будет использовать сотни тысяч или даже миллионы человек? Будет ли корректно работать такой подход и не возникнут ли у Гугл претензии ко мне как к пользователю их сервисов?

Надеюсь на ваши ответы. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Претензии наверняка возникнут. Ибо для таких целей существуют сервисы cloud.google а они достаточно дороги в использовании.

Comment: Откройте условия использования и прочтите первоисточник, для коммерческого использования нужно покупать один из пакетов G Suite https://www.google.com/drive/terms-of-service/

Comment: Хорошо, я вас понял. Как тогда можно решить этот вопрос? И вообще, чисто технически это нормальная практика, когда размещают подобные ресурсы тупо в облаке? Или по-хорошему надо использовать именно сервер? Ради хранения картинок не хотелось бы так изголяться, конечно.

Comment: Как-то не вяжутся их корпоративные пакеты на такую задачу, в них предоставляется куча не нужных услуг. В общем ситуация не понятная - лучше задайте вопрос им в тех. поддержку или посмотрите какой-то другой сервис. Точно могу сказать что использовать гугл-диски пользователей в приложении можно ([пример](https://habr.com/ru/post/440844/)), а насчёт шарить им свои файлы как-то непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в [сторону Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc), там есть бесплатный вариант для размещения. По параметрам должно подойти.

Второй вариант - получить такой же [бесплатный доступ у гугла](https://cloud.google.com/free/), к их облаку. Но про него я знаю мало.